# How to calculate the percentage of similarity or difference between two texts / strings?

Tags: php, string, text-processing

Explaining it further

Assume i have two strings like below

> I am a super boy who can Fly! Really .
>
> I am super boy who can Break walls!
>   Really .

So some characters are similar `I am super boy who can` and `Really .` .
Is there anything ready to use to find percentage similarity/diffrence between those two strings.

Comment: This depends on how do you define similarity...

Comment: I am very curious to see your implementation.

Comment: @Gertjan apologies  , read late .PHP has inbuilt functions for these comparisons . One awesome theory/algo by Levenshtein http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php , and second with percentage results http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php .  * I LOVE PHP * :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into Levenshtein Distance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 0):

This [SO answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236357/4852737) gives the PHP code for the Levenshtein, Jaro Winkler and Smith Waterman Gotoh algorithms.

I've found that Levenshtein and Jaro Winkler generally give good results for spelling mistakes between smaller strings. While the Smith Waterman Gotoh [is good at comparing sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235657/4852737) like the example in your question.