# How do I find if a string(A) exists in another string(B) using c#?

Tags: c#, string

Before marking this as duplicate, please read the details here.

**Example 1:**

```
String A: The seven habits of highly effective people.

String B: "This is a sample text. There is only one product in it. It is a book. The book is The seven habits of highly effective people."
```

**Example 2:**

```
String A: The seven habits of highly effective people.

String B: "This is a sample text. There is only one product in it. It is a book. The book is The seven habits of highly effective peopl."
```

Now solving the above examples with a code like
 
`B.Contains(A)` 
will give the correct results. However the same code will return "false" as output in Example 2.

How do I resolve this problem?

**There is an "e" missing in example 2 and I am aware about it and that's the problem. How do I compare one string with another where string A is nearly identical with a "part of string B"?**

Comment: example 2 doesnt contain A

Comment: @user1039119 - Same code returns "false" as output in Example 2,as the complete string is not there. what you want to achieve ?

Comment: At the end of string B in ex.2, you have *peopl.* not *people.*

Comment: The strings in example 2 are obviously different - if you want to get matches for "nearly indentical" strings it gets difficult very fast, simply because defining "nearly identical" is fun.

Comment: Do you see difference between both examples?

Comment: Isn't people missing an 'e' in example 2?

Comment: @Christian, Exactly, that's what I want. How to define the nearly identical string.?

Comment: There is an "e" missing in example 2 and I am aware about it.

Comment: You might consider something like the Levenshtein Distance algorithm.. but I am unsure how well that will perform for such large input strings (it works fine for smaller ones). Wiki here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: What you're looking for is measuring how similar two strings are, then setting some threshold for how similar "similar enough" is. [This question looks like a good place to start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453731/how-to-calculate-distance-similarity-measure-of-given-2-strings)

Comment: Fyi I have used Levenshtein for caching "sounds like" results on small words and it was fine. I suggest benchmarking though.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment.. the Levenshtein Distance algorithm (and similar ones) compute differences between strings and return a numerical result (wiki: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

However, I would definitely apply benchmarking and caching strategies for these algorithms. They are decent with small input.. but when I have implemented it I have had to make sure I cache results / lookups. Your large example will not perform "fast".. depending on what "fast" is for your use case.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your answer. I have gone through the details about the algorithm you mentioned. However, the problem I am facing is not about comparing two nearly identical strings. The Problem is comparing one string with "part of another string" which is nearly identical. As shown in the example I mentioned, only a part of String B matches string A. hence the distance algorithm may not give accurate results.

Comment: @user1039119 you can calculate it, for example, `bool contains = Math.Abs(Math.Abs(strB.Length - strA.Length) - levenshteinDistance) < 3;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.compare`, Find below few examples which may help you.

```
string a = "a"; 
string b = "b"; 
int c;

c = string.Compare(a, b);
Console.WriteLine(c);

c = string.CompareOrdinal(b, a);
Console.WriteLine(c);

c = a.CompareTo(b);
Console.WriteLine(c);

c = b.CompareTo(a);
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for looks like a search engine with score rate.

I used the Levenshtein Distance methode to search/compare string that looks like the same but who are not.

there is an example at the following link :

http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein

Answer (score 0):

**I am answering my own question.**

I was looking for a solution to compare one string with another where **string A** is ***nearly identical*** with a "**part of string B**".

This is how I resolved the issue.

1. I applied the "[Longest Common Substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)" algorithm and founded
   the longest common substring between the two strings.
2. Then I used "Levenshtein Distance algorithm" to compare my String A with the "Longest Common Substring" found from step 1.
3. If the result available from the algorithm mentioned in step 2 is
   above certain threshold, then it implies that the string A exists in String B.
4. *Problem Solved*.

I have worked on the problem for one day and I have found decent results for the problem.