# use custom compare function in set equality python

Tags: python, set

I wish to use a custom compare function while calculating set. I wish to take advantage of the efficiencies of using set algorithm. technically I could create a double for loop to compare the two lists (keep, original) but I thought this might not be efficient.

eg://

```
textlist = ["ravi is happy", "happy ravi is", "is happy ravi", "is ravi happy"]
```

`set()` should return only 1 of these elements as the compare function would return if True if similarity between comparing `items >= threshold`.

In python. Thanks.

P.S.

The real trick is that I'd like to use my `string_compare(t1,t2): Float` to do the comparison rather then hashing and equal...

P.S.S.

C# has similar function:
[How to remove similar string from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817590/how-to-remove-similar-string-from-a-list)

Comment: That's not how sets work. They're implemented using a hash table, so you need to write a hash function that returns the same value for all similar strings.

Comment: Also, the hash function is associated with the objects, not the set. So you'd need to create a subclass of `str`.

Comment: if for example. I convert each string to a INT of unique ID for each char (assuming ASCII) will __eq__ be called when calculating if the two elements are equal?

so far I have something like this:

`class string_wrap(object):

    def __init__(self, t):
  self.t=t

 def __eq__(self, other):
  return string_compare(self.t, other.t) >= simthreshold

 def __hash__(self):
  return hash(self.t)`

Comment: It uses `__hash__` to find the hash bucket, then searches the bucket to find an element that's `__eq__`.

Comment: What is `t`? The hash function has to return a number.

Comment: See https://www.asmeurer.com/blog/posts/what-happens-when-you-mess-with-hashing-in-python/ for a good explanation.

Comment: t is a string in this case. I use wrap each element in the list with string_wrap. then compute set on the new list.

Comment: Oh, I see you wrote `hash(self.t)`. But that won't return the same hash code for all the similar strings.

Comment: You could try something like `return hash(self.t.sorted())` so the hash code won't depend on the character order.

Comment: But this really depends on your definition of similar. Are `happy` and `hippy` similar, since they only have 1 character difference?

Comment: similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306844/custom-comparison-functions-for-built-in-types-in-python

the similarity function I wrote it's called string_compare returns 0->1 float

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were looking for:

```
{' '.join(sorted(sentence.split())) for sentence in textlist}
```

This re-orders the string and therefore Python set will now work because we are comparing identical strings.