# C# Looking for similar needle in haystack (for OCR)

Tags: c#, string, ocr

I've been working on an OCR program that accepts a photo with text in it (in this specific case, a driver's license) as well as a first name and a last name as arguments.

Once the software reads the id photo, I search for the first and last name in the recognized text. Unfortunately, as the image quality can be pretty low, it will sometimes not get the name *quite* right.

Is there a way I could look for a SIMILAR needle in a haystack? That is, look for any occurrences that are similar to the first/last name? For example:

```
Needle: campbell

Haystack: 
operaioxsllcence 
gcltdriver 
exries13NOV2020
carnpbeiljtttj
...
```

The string that would be close enough is "carnpbeil".

This is what I'm using now, and it only helps in very specific situations:

```
private bool SourceContains(string haystack, string needle)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        if (haystack.Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("l", "i").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("i", "l").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("0", "o").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("o", "0").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("j", "d").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("d", "j").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("i", "j").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("j", "i").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("e", "f").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("f", "e").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("r", "p").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("p", "r").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("s", "r").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("r", "s").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("r", "n").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("n", "r").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("k", "n").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("n", "k").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("h", "n").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("n", "h").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("k", "ll").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("ll", "k").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("ci", "d").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("d", "ci").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("cl", "d").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("d", "cl").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("m", "in").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("in", "m").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("rn", "m").Contains(needle) ||
                haystack.Replace("m", "rn").Contains(needle)
                )
        {
            ret = true;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For each word in `haystack` calculate the [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to `needle`. The word with the shortest distance is most likely to be your needle. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9453731/1576119) for implementations.

Comment: Unfortunately, the words detected are sometimes not split up properly. Like in the example I showed, "carnpbeil" would be the match for Campbell (the letters LOOK the same), but the "word" is "carnpbeiljtttj", as it also mashed the first name in with the last.

I think that the only way I'm going to improve on this is to increase the quality of the images that are submitted.