# PHP String Comparison and similarity index

Tags: php

What's an elegant code for finding common alphabets among two strings without including the space in PHP?

Also return a similarity index i.e. count the number of common characters and return that as a percentage over the total number of characters.

Suppose i have one string "LEGENDARY  ", whereas other as "BARNEY STINSON" so i need to find common letters b/w both without including space.

Also my code should return a similarity index i.e. count the number of common characters and return that as a percentage over the total number of characters.

For these two strings, the common characters are "ARNEY" so the score is 5/22 ~= 22%. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [`similar_text()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php). And if you want to exclude spaces simple `str_replace(' ', '', $string);` prior.

```
echo similar_text ( 'LEGENDARY' , 'BARNEYSTINSON', $percent); // outputs 3
echo $percent; // outputs 27.272727272727
```

Here's another way using only unique characters

```
<?php
function unique_chars($string) {
   return count_chars(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $string)), 3);
}
function compare_strings($a, $b) {
    $index = similar_text(unique_chars($a), unique_chars($b), $percent);
    return array('index' => $index, 'percent' => $percent);
}
print_r( compare_strings('LEGENDARY', 'BARNEY STINSON') );

// outputs:
?>

Array
(
    [index] => 5
    [percent] => 55.555555555556
)
```

Comment: but the common characters are 5 among the strings, so the result should be 5/22 = 22.2%

Comment: So do you want to not count duplicates? cause if you cound the N 3 times in `BARNEY STINSON` there are 7 similar chars.

Comment: Yes, i don't want to count the duplicates. I just want to show the common alphabets of the two strings, count their no. and count total characters in both the strings (excluding the space) and show the percentage.

Comment: But then you go and calculate the percent using all the characters. That is not accurate. I think you want to do the percent based only on unique characters first. I'll edit with an example.

Answer (score 10):

I've found that to calculate a similarity percentage between strings, the [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and [Jaro Winkler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) algorithms work well for spelling mistakes and small changes between strings, while the [Smith Waterman Gotoh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) algorithm works well for strings where significant chunks of the text would be the same but with "noise" around the edges. [This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235657/4852737) shows more detail on this.

Here are php examples of using each of these three examples to return a similarity percentage between two strings:

### [Levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

```
echo levenshtein("LEGENDARY","BARNEY STINSON");
```

### [Jaro Winkler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236260/4852737)

```
class StringCompareJaroWinkler 
{
    public function compare($str1, $str2)
    {
        return $this->JaroWinkler($str1, $str2, $PREFIXSCALE = 0.1 );
    }

    private function getCommonCharacters( $string1, $string2, $allowedDistance ){

      $str1_len = mb_strlen($string1);
      $str2_len = mb_strlen($string2);
      $temp_string2 = $string2;

      $commonCharacters='';
      for( $i=0; $i < $str1_len; $i++){

        $noMatch = True;
        // compare if char does match inside given allowedDistance
        // and if it does add it to commonCharacters
        for( $j= max( 0, $i-$allowedDistance ); $noMatch && $j < min( $i + $allowedDistance + 1, $str2_len ); $j++){
          if( $temp_string2[$j] == $string1[$i] ){
            $noMatch = False;
        $commonCharacters .= $string1[$i];
        $temp_string2[$j] = '';
          }
        }
      }
      return $commonCharacters;
    }

    private function Jaro( $string1, $string2 ){

      $str1_len = mb_strlen( $string1 );
      $str2_len = mb_strlen( $string2 );

      // theoretical distance
      $distance = (int) floor(min( $str1_len, $str2_len ) / 2.0); 

      // get common characters
      $commons1 = $this->getCommonCharacters( $string1, $string2, $distance );
      $commons2 = $this->getCommonCharacters( $string2, $string1, $distance );

      if( ($commons1_len = mb_strlen( $commons1 )) == 0) return 0;
      if( ($commons2_len = mb_strlen( $commons2 )) == 0) return 0;
      // calculate transpositions
      $transpositions = 0;
      $upperBound = min( $commons1_len, $commons2_len );
      for( $i = 0; $i < $upperBound; $i++){
        if( $commons1[$i] != $commons2[$i] ) $transpositions++;
      }
      $transpositions /= 2.0;
      // return the Jaro distance
      return ($commons1_len/($str1_len) + $commons2_len/($str2_len) + ($commons1_len - $transpositions)/($commons1_len)) / 3.0;

    }

    private function getPrefixLength( $string1, $string2, $MINPREFIXLENGTH = 4 ){

      $n = min( array( $MINPREFIXLENGTH, mb_strlen($string1), mb_strlen($string2) ) );

      for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
        if( $string1[$i] != $string2[$i] ){
          // return index of first occurrence of different characters 
          return $i;
        }
      }
      // first n characters are the same   
      return $n;
    }

    private function JaroWinkler($string1, $string2, $PREFIXSCALE = 0.1 ){

      $JaroDistance = $this->Jaro( $string1, $string2 );
      $prefixLength = $this->getPrefixLength( $string1, $string2 );
      return $JaroDistance + $prefixLength * $PREFIXSCALE * (1.0 - $JaroDistance);
    }
}

$jw = new StringCompareJaroWinkler();
echo $jw->compare("LEGENDARY","BARNEY STINSON");
```

### [Smith Waterman Gotoh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235828/4852737)

```
class SmithWatermanGotoh 
{
    private $gapValue;
    private $substitution;

    /**
     * Constructs a new Smith Waterman metric.
     * 
     * @param gapValue
     *            a non-positive gap penalty
     * @param substitution
     *            a substitution function
     */
    public function __construct($gapValue=-0.5, 
                $substitution=null) 
    {
        if($gapValue > 0.0) throw new Exception("gapValue must be <= 0");
        //if(empty($substitution)) throw new Exception("substitution is required");
        if (empty($substitution)) $this->substitution = new SmithWatermanMatchMismatch(1.0, -2.0);
        else $this->substitution = $substitution;
        $this->gapValue = $gapValue;
    }

    public function compare($a, $b) 
    {
        if (empty($a) && empty($b)) {
            return 1.0;
        }

        if (empty($a) || empty($b)) {
            return 0.0;
        }

        $maxDistance = min(mb_strlen($a), mb_strlen($b))
                * max($this->substitution->max(), $this->gapValue);
        return $this->smithWatermanGotoh($a, $b) / $maxDistance;
    }

    private function smithWatermanGotoh($s, $t) 
    {   
        $v0 = [];
        $v1 = [];
        $t_len = mb_strlen($t);
        $max = $v0[0] = max(0, $this->gapValue, $this->substitution->compare($s, 0, $t, 0));

        for ($j = 1; $j < $t_len; $j++) {
            $v0[$j] = max(0, $v0[$j - 1] + $this->gapValue,
                    $this->substitution->compare($s, 0, $t, $j));

            $max = max($max, $v0[$j]);
        }

        // Find max
        for ($i = 1; $i < mb_strlen($s); $i++) {
            $v1[0] = max(0, $v0[0] + $this->gapValue, $this->substitution->compare($s, $i, $t, 0));

            $max = max($max, $v1[0]);

            for ($j = 1; $j < $t_len; $j++) {
                $v1[$j] = max(0, $v0[$j] + $this->gapValue, $v1[$j - 1] + $this->gapValue,
                        $v0[$j - 1] + $this->substitution->compare($s, $i, $t, $j));

                $max = max($max, $v1[$j]);
            }

            for ($j = 0; $j < $t_len; $j++) {
                $v0[$j] = $v1[$j];
            }
        }

        return $max;
    }
}

class SmithWatermanMatchMismatch
{
    private $matchValue;
    private $mismatchValue;

    /**
     * Constructs a new match-mismatch substitution function. When two
     * characters are equal a score of <code>matchValue</code> is assigned. In
     * case of a mismatch a score of <code>mismatchValue</code>. The
     * <code>matchValue</code> must be strictly greater then
     * <code>mismatchValue</code>
     * 
     * @param matchValue
     *            value when characters are equal
     * @param mismatchValue
     *            value when characters are not equal
     */
    public function __construct($matchValue, $mismatchValue) {
        if($matchValue <= $mismatchValue) throw new Exception("matchValue must be > matchValue");

        $this->matchValue = $matchValue;
        $this->mismatchValue = $mismatchValue;
    }

    public function compare($a, $aIndex, $b, $bIndex) {
        return ($a[$aIndex] === $b[$bIndex] ? $this->matchValue
                : $this->mismatchValue);
    }

    public function max() {
        return $this->matchValue;
    }

    public function min() {
        return $this->mismatchValue;
    }
}

$o = new SmithWatermanGotoh();
echo $o->compare("LEGENDARY","BARNEY STINSON");
```

Comment: Really useful! Thanks.

Comment: I am using _StringCompareJaroWinkler_  I am comparing a single string to a set of records in a loop. I am getting this PHP Warning: _Cannot assign an empty string to a string_. Anyone know why?